# Socket Rocket Test/Tutorial

Tags: iphone, ios, websocket, socketrocket

I'm new to socketrocket and to iOS development. I'm trying to follow along at https://github.com/square/SocketRocket#readme and implement the basic test chat app but am having trouble making things work.

Beginning with "go into the SocketRocket root directory and type: make test" i need some help.

Using the mac terminal, 'make' isn't a recognized command. Do i need to have python enabled on my mac for this to work at all? Trying to run the testapp in xcode before the server is started does nothing.

A more bare bones explanation would be most appreciated

Comment: Have you installed the command line tools from Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install command line tools. make is for compiling c code (among other things) command line tools can be downloaded with xcode through the app store.